# Firebase: Filter child node query on AngularFire2 firebase

Tags: javascript, ionic, firebase, typescript, ionic3

Tenho essa seguinte estrutura:

```
{
  "3" : {
    "data" : "2017-09-21",
    "fornecedor" : {
      "cnpj" : "123234534534",
      "fantasia" : "Barreirinha"
    },
    "nNF" : 3,
    "peso" : 3,
    "precoCompra" : 6,
    "vendido" : false
  },
  "123" : {
    "data" : "2017-09-14",
    "fornecedor" : {
      "cnpj" : "123234534534",
      "fantasia" : "Barreirinha"
    },
    "nNF" : 123,
    "peso" : 23000,
    "precoCompra" : 2.21,
    "vendido" : false
  }
}
```

Eu preciso filtrar essa lista com somente os resultados em que o nó fornecedor com o atributo CNPJ seja igual ao parâmetro enviado.

Estou tentando algo desse tipo, mas não estou conseguindo resultado, não retorna nada.

```
const rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
return rootRef.child('produtos/').orderByChild('fornecedor/cnpj').equalTo('123234534534');
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução rápida é pegar essa lista usando o evento "value" do firebase, e usar o operador filter da rxjs no lado do cliente. Outra maneira de fazer é usando as functionshosts do firebase para processar a requisição no lado do servidor e devolver a resposta já processada.

Comment: Entendo, não existe nada mais simples será? Que se resolva no orderByChild ou equalto? Um modo de fazer ele retornar os registros do pai tendo como filtro o filho?